# How to do Form Customization for Unhiding Fields

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am new to Ax,I am doing an customization on form.When I click on show more fields I want to show three more fields on form which are hiding(FieldC,FieldD,FieldF).Please tell me how to achieve this Functionality.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain on what condition to view C, D and F?
Are you using an ordinary form or are you using the Dialog class or Runbase framework?

Comment: Hello Sir , I am creating an simple form and taking help from this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/how-to-hide-fields-on-a-dialog-form) but can't be able to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check an example in *form VendTable > Design > MainTab > TabPageDetails > Tab > TabGeneral > HideShowGroup*.

It contains two elements: a combobox (*HideShowComboBox*) and a button (*HideShowButton*).

By default, the button has following properties:

- AutoDeclaration = Yes
- Text = Show more fields
- HelpText = Show/hide fields.
- SaveRecord = No
- Border = None
- BackgroundColor = Dyn Background white
- ImageLocation = EmbeddedResource
- NormalImage = 7886
- ButtonDisplay = Text & Image left

The button also has method `clicked` responsible for hiding/showing the fields that need to be hidden/displayed and for changing its own look (Text, HelpText, NormalImage = 7882, etc.)

Please note that this logic is managed in class `DirPartyFormHandler` - you can set breakpoints there and debug the process to understand this functionality better.